# When to use React.PropsWithChildren

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-props

In what to me seems like two similar setups, on one machine I was allowed to call

```
<MyApp
        accountId={this.props.accountId}
        children={toggleButton} />
```

Where MyApp had the class signature

```
export interface IMyAppProps {
  accountId: string;
  dispatch: any;
}
    class MyApp extends React.Component<IMyAppProps, IMyAppState> {
```

On the other machine, running `npm run-script build` fails with

> TypeScript build error TS2322: Type ' ... ' is not assignable to type ' ... '
>
> Property 'children' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes &
>   Pick<IMyAppProps, "accountId">'

Versions used on both machines react-scripts-ts 4.0.8, typescript 3.4.5.

Changing the class definition to this made it work on both machines

```
class MyApp extends React.Component<React.PropsWithChildren<IMyAppProps>, IMyAppState> {
```

I am unsure why it works in one setup and not the other. When do I wrap my props interface in `React.PropsWithChildren`?

My best guess would be that the change is to be found in a typings file for React or for a React-related package.

Comment: was wondering this myself as well as a newbie in React, voted up and hopefully we can both get an answer

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't know why it worked on one machine but not the other but I don't think that's the right way to use the `children` property.

Instead of this ...

```
<MyApp
        accountId={this.props.accountId}
        children={toggleButton} />
```

... I think the purpose of `children` is to let you call something like this ...

```
<MyApp accountId={this.props.accountId}>
  <ToggleButton/>
</MyApp>
```

... or something like that.

The child or children -- `<ToggleButton/>` in my example above -- might be a React element, or text (a text node), or `undefined` if there is no child, or maybe an expression like `{toggleButton}` which evaluates to one of the child types.

Answer (score 2):

The actual answer has nothing to do with whether you use `<MyApp children={...}` or `<MyApp><Child /></MyApp>`.  The difference is that in the first example `IMyAppProps` does not have a `children` property defined, so TypeScript complains that you can't use it like that.  When you wrap it in `WithChildren` that adds a `children` property to the interface.

Comment: We didn't have this issue until now, we haven't even updated React, then suddenly, boom this explodes in our face for the entire codebase. Where does it come from?

Comment: My guess would be that you probably didn't have this error before because you didn't have `@types/react` installed so there was nothing for it to check, and thens somebody added it.